# Route 'checkout' not defined

Tags: routes

[Route 'checkout' not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c77Gg.png)

Route web :
Route::post('/checkout', [CheckoutController::class, 'process'])->name('checkout');

Blade :

@csrf
            
            .....

Answer (score 0):

It must be in route group thats why its is unable to access this route try php artisan route:list and it will show the correct name for this checkout url